# What are the causes of Buffered state in Durable Entities?

Tags: c#, azure-durable-functions

I have a durable entity definition of:

```cs
public class OrchestrationData : IOrchestrationData
{
    [FunctionName(nameof(OrchestrationData))]
        public static Task Run([EntityTrigger] IDurableEntityContext context)
            => context.DispatchAsync<OrchestrationData>();

    [JsonProperty("taskLanguages")] 
        public List<MyLang> TaskLanguages { get; set; } = new List<MyLang>();

    public Task SetTaskLanguages(MyLangCol languages)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => 
        {
            TaskLanguages.AddRange(languages.MyLangs);
        });
    }
}
```

I call the `SetTaskLanguages` method from my orchestrator:

```cs
    IOrchestrationData proxy2 = context.CreateEntityProxy<IOrchestrationData>(entityId);
    MyLangCol mlc = new MyLangCol
        { MyLangs = languages.Select(l => new MyLang { LangIso = l.LangIso }).ToArray() };
    await proxy2.SetTaskLanguages(mlc);
```

However, when I query the state of the entity it says it is `Buffered` and none of the subsequent calls in my orchestrator have executed so I am missing all state updates after this call.

```json
{
   "exists": true,
   "state": "{\"orchestrationId\":\"88d125873c6c415683f1efddccb97665\",\"taskLanguages\":[],\"translationStatuses\":null,\"Projects\":[]}",
   "sorter": {
      "ReceivedFromInstance": {
         "88d125873c6c415683f1efddccb97665": {
            "Last": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "ExecutionId": "ec184846d0ce443f8fff17b63a0167ff",
            "Buffered": {
               "2023-07-07T18:39:36Z": {
                  "op": "SetTaskLanguages",
                  "signal": true,
                  "input": "{\"myLangs\":[{\"langIso\":\"en_US\"},{\"langIso\":\"es\"},{\"langIso\":\"it\"},{\"langIso\":\"de\"}]}",
                  "id": "0818c4e3-17ed-5b5b-9375-1fcb34dedb88",
                  "parent": "88d125873c6c415683f1efddccb97665",
                  "parentExecution": "ec184846d0ce443f8fff17b63a0167ff",
                  "Timestamp": "2023-07-07T18:39:36Z",
                  "Predecessor": "2023-07-07T18:39:30Z"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "ReceiveHorizon": "2023-07-07T18:09:36Z"
   }
}
```

I have tried everything during local debug and cannot see why it is buffering. If I remove the call `proxy2.SetTaskLanguages(mlc)` then all my subsequent state updates work perfectly.

Comment: Anecdotally, I am experiencing problems with Durable Entity properties which are either `string` or `string[]`. Wrapping them in another type works more reliably.

Comment: Is it possible that calling a durable entity more than once from within the same orchestration, even if separated with a durable delay, is causing a problem? I had a call to the durable entity earlier in my orchestration and commenting it out allows the above call to work. :-/

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run`?

Comment: Because the method returns a `Task`. I have tried combinations without `Task.Run()` and same behavior. The only way I can get this to work is to ensure that I only have one call to an entity per orchestrator.

Comment: I found [this apparent duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71904082/120955). I notice they're also trying to change state inside of a call to `Task.Run`. Can you put together a minimal reproducible example that doesn't create a separate execution context?